# Data input comparison in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate input from PHP and possibly detect what type of attack has been attempted (if any).

```
...

    $data = array($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE);

    foreach($data as $entryPoint){
        foreach($SQLi as $vector){
            if($entryPoint==$vector){
                echo 'SQLi detected';
            }
        }
    }
...
```

And so I have in my `$SQLi` array the following:

```
$SQLi  = array(

'UNION ALL','SELECT','DISTINCT','AUTO INCREMENT','VERSION()',
'GROUP','CONCAT','@@VERSION','FLOOR','information_schema',
'COUNT','INSERT INTO','DROP','ORDER BY','UPDATE'

);
```

I wanna check if any of the elements in that array are present as values of either `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_COOKIE` requests. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These types of "attacks" will happen unintentionally, so logging or detecting them will just result in a log file containing single quotes, special characters, etc. Just make sure the code can handle any type of attack, [SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) or [XSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php), or others (there are other types). And this idea of checking different arrays doesn't make sense either.

Comment: You're doing wrong everything. This whole idea makes no sense.

Comment: You are want to find the SQLi keywords *IN* the data, not equal to the data.

Comment: In case you're wondering, you can use `strstr()` to find a string inside another. But really though, this doesn't make much sense... `$entryPoint` will contain arrays (not strings).

Comment: agreed with the first two comments. not only is this the wrong implementation of what you are trying to do, what you're trying to do is the complete wrong approach to making a secure PHP application/script. Read up on web security especially with user submitted data and take your time learning this topic and how to prevent attacks.

Comment: That's part of a WAF. I've already sanitized all the input so now I need to detect what has been attempted and report back the results to a 3rd party page.

Comment: @user3794668: "I've already sanitized all the input" --- it makes no sense either.

Comment: Ok whatever my purpose, that's not the actual topic after all.

Comment: Well, stackoverflow community usually prevents users from doing *stupid* things. In this case you've been told multiple times but still confident we're wrong. Good luck then! ;-D

Comment: @zerkms Seeing how community give answers for wrong questions, I'd say they don't care preventing stupid things to do.

Comment: @djay: a lot of here do care. Including me :-) That's why a lot of people here think I'm a douche bag :-D

Comment: How should I identify the attack otherwise? This is purely for my own reference and log information.

Comment: @user3794668: why do you need to identify "the attack" if your app is bullet-proof against it?

Comment: You should not. This has been done before million times by another developers. You can check how this is done in frameworks

Comment: Let's say to inform the admin of what has been attempted against his web application, restrict the IP, log information about the vector and request itself etc.

Comment: This needs to be done in OOP-way anyway. You need a validation layer for that

Comment: @user3794668: "restrict the IP" --- so if you click a random link in the internet (possibly short linked one) - you will end up being banned? Anyway, I'm surprised that a confident developer who knows how to develop secured applications cannot implement 3 lines script: 1. loop 2. `stripos` 3. your action

Comment: Why not use @zerkms's suggestion; compare the before string to the after string (of `stripos`).  If they are different, then there was an attack attempt (at least, you can consider it that way in your records).

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that:

```
$data = array($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE);
$SQLi  = array(

'UNION ALL','SELECT','DISTINCT','AUTO INCREMENT','VERSION()',
'GROUP','CONCAT','@@VERSION','FLOOR','information_schema',
'COUNT','INSERT INTO','DROP','ORDER BY','UPDATE'

);
foreach($data as $entryPoint){
    foreach($entryPoint as $value){
        foreach($SQLi as $attack){
            if($attack==$value){
                echo "SQLi detected";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Looks like strpos can break your code, since it will even detect an 'L' as an SQLi.

Comment: That's still detecting whole string matches, you should be looking for partial matches in the string

Comment: Yeah, you might want to replace `in_array()` with `strpos`

Comment: @djay Why `strpos` if he wants to see if the contents are in an array?

Comment: because of scrowler's comment. That's why